# visual studio 2012 virtual memory range for PCH exceeded

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Error   3   error C3859: virtual memory range for PCH exceeded; please recompile with a command line option of '-Zm163' or greater  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstring  1810

This http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdscwf1c.aspx is killing my butthole for real.

Im stuck at Click the c/c++ folder..

1. Click the C/C++ folder.
2. Click the Command Line property page.
3. Type the compiler option in the Additional Options box.

http://www.mediafire.com/view/skb2y7y45hp4svy

Comment: 0: Right-click the *project* node and click Properties.  You right-clicked the Solution node instead.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you in the "solution" level properties while you should be on the "Project" level properties.

you can easily get there by right click on the project in the "Solution Explorer" and then choose the last option in the menu "properties".